# USB-C Connector: How to properly route on EAGLE CAD to supply power to PCB

Tags: pcb, usb, pcb-design, eaglecad, usb-c

So basically, I am needing to power my PCB using an additional USB 2.0 Type-C connector, but was having trouble understanding the pinout on eagle versus a typical USB Type-A where I could use VCC and GND and neglect the other pins.

Looking at this footprint pinout below, if anyone could explain to me how I should properly route or use these pins, I would definetely appreciate it, thanks in advance!

***Component Model : USB4085-GF-A***

[image]

Comment: There is something seriously wrong with your "footprint pinout". USB Type-C connector has 4 VBUS and 4 GND pins. You need to select first a connector you can afford (in terms of PCB mounting, SMT soldering, etc.), and then use their manufacturer's supplied footprint.

Comment: Could it be that the symbol routes the one net to all of the same net pins on the footprint, to simplify the schematic symbol?

Comment: It's quite common to encounter USB C connectors with less pins on the PCB side than on the cable side. I presume this is done to support use of USB C connectors with lower-end PCB fabrication and assembly processes.

Answer (score 1):

Both CC pins need to be pulled down separately with 5.1K resistors.

If you leave the CC pins open, then a USB C power supply won't turn on.

If you tie the CC pins together and pull them down with a single 5.1K resistor, it will work with a passive cable, but will fail with at least some active cables.

If you pull down only one of the CC pins then it will probablly only work with the cable one way up.

Answer (score 0):

If you want power between Vbus and GND then you’ll need to terminate one of the CC pins.

If terminated correctly you should be able to draw 500mA at 5V without the need for negotiation.

You can read more in [this Cypress document](https://community.cypress.com/docs/DOC-10779) or this [Silicon Labs Note](https://www.silabs.com/community/mcu/8-bit/knowledge-base.entry.html/2016/09/26/what_s_the_role_ofc-kQYe).

You may find it easier to use a USB2 specific connector such as micro-B, though you’d be limited to 100mA (by the specification, many wall chargers and even hosts don’t limit it).